# Grouping markers near together with the same cluster size by google map

Tags: javascript, dictionary, markerclusterer

I want to group all markers near together with **the same cluster size** using google map.

I tried MarkerClusterer supported by Google Map, but the cluster size are different.

Is there any example for me?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can show what you have tried so far. Please see this first [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

[**Understanding marker clustering**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering)

> The **MarkerClusterer** library uses the grid-based clustering
>   technique that divides the map into squares of a certain size (the
>   size changes at each zoom level), and groups the markers into each
>   square grid. It creates a cluster at a particular marker, and adds
>   markers that are in its bounds to the cluster. It repeats this process
>   until all markers are allocated to the closest grid-based marker
>   clusters based on the map's zoom level. If markers are in the bounds
>   of more than one existing cluster, the Maps JavaScript API determines
>   the marker's distance from each cluster, and adds it to the closest
>   cluster.
>
> You can set a **MarkerClusterer** option to adjust the cluster
>   position to reflect the average distance between all the markers that
>   are contained within it. You can also customize the
>   **MarkerClusterer** to modify other parameters like the grid size, the cluster 
>   icon, cluster text, among others.

Take a look at below example:

I have used `gridSize` parameter to set a grouping value to my markers. This way you can achieve what you're looking for.

```js
function initMap() {

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 3,
    center: {
      lat: -28.024,
      lng: 140.887
    }
  });

  // Create an array of alphabetical characters used to label the markers.
  var labels = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

  // Add some markers to the map.
  // Note: The code uses the JavaScript Array.prototype.map() method to
  // create an array of markers based on a given "locations" array.
  // The map() method here has nothing to do with the Google Maps API.
  var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
    return new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      label: labels[i % labels.length]
    });
  });

  // Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
  var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
    imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m',
    gridSize: 10
  });
}
var locations = [{
    lat: -31.563910,
    lng: 147.154312
  },
  {
    lat: -33.718234,
    lng: 150.363181
  },
  {
    lat: -33.727111,
    lng: 150.371124
  },
  {
    lat: -33.848588,
    lng: 151.209834
  },
  {
    lat: -33.851702,
    lng: 151.216968
  },
  {
    lat: -34.671264,
    lng: 150.863657
  },
  {
    lat: -35.304724,
    lng: 148.662905
  },
  {
    lat: -36.817685,
    lng: 175.699196
  },
  {
    lat: -36.828611,
    lng: 175.790222
  },
  {
    lat: -37.750000,
    lng: 145.116667
  },
  {
    lat: -37.759859,
    lng: 145.128708
  },
  {
    lat: -37.765015,
    lng: 145.133858
  },
  {
    lat: -37.770104,
    lng: 145.143299
  },
  {
    lat: -37.773700,
    lng: 145.145187
  },
  {
    lat: -37.774785,
    lng: 145.137978
  },
  {
    lat: -37.819616,
    lng: 144.968119
  },
  {
    lat: -38.330766,
    lng: 144.695692
  },
  {
    lat: -39.927193,
    lng: 175.053218
  },
  {
    lat: -41.330162,
    lng: 174.865694
  },
  {
    lat: -42.734358,
    lng: 147.439506
  },
  {
    lat: -42.734358,
    lng: 147.501315
  },
  {
    lat: -42.735258,
    lng: 147.438000
  },
  {
    lat: -43.999792,
    lng: 170.463352
  },
  {
    lat: -43.998792,
    lng: 170.463352
  },
  {
    lat: -43.999792,
    lng: 170.413352
  },
  {
    lat: -43.999000,
    lng: 170.463000
  }
]
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js">
</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBplDzEjv3SUmKPKj0IY-Iq4u_nB3z2Q1I&callback=initMap">
</script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

For an advance example, please take a look at this -> [An example of MarkerClusterer v3](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/examples/advanced_example.html) and for all examples, click [here](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/docs/examples.html).